# how to return record without null values

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, group-by

How do you query to return one row having the values 500, 250 without subqueries?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DemoTbl]
(
    [ACount] [int] NULL,
    [BCount] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[DemoTbl] ([ACount], [BCount]) VALUES (NULL, 250)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[DemoTbl] ([ACount], [BCount]) VALUES (500, NULL)
```

Comment: You might want to ask another question if your table has more than two rows.

Answer (score 0):

For this dataset, you can just use aggregation:

```
select max(acount) acount, max(bcount) bcount
from mytable
```

Comment: Welcome @tinafmills. If my answer properly responded to your question, then [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) by clicking the check sign... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to coalesce the `nulls` into some non-null value that lies outside the domain of the column (meaning, some value that will not otherwise occur).

This answer, by @GMB, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62585518/467473, collapsing all the rows of the result set into a single row, which is a completely different representation of the data.

If you have a table that looks like

```
  A    B    C
---- ---- ----
  1  null   6  
null   5  null
  8    3    2
```

and run the query

```sql
select max(A) as A,
       max(B) as B,
       max(C)
from example_table
```

You will get the 1-row result set

```sql
  A    B    C
---- ---- ----
  8    5    6
```

which is probably not what you're looking for.

So, you want to say something along the lines of (using my example table above):

```sql
select coalesce(A,-1) as A,
       coalesce(B,-1) as B,
       coalesce(C,-1) as C
from example_table
```

which yields

```
  A    B    C
---- ---- ----
  1   -1    6  
 -1    5   -1
  8    3    2
```

[The recipient of the data still has to decide what to do with the missing/unknown values (what `null` represents) in each tuple, but you've maintained the identity of the tuples and the cardinality of the result set.]